Nextjs route intercept modal not dismissing after submitting the form
/guestlist/@modal/(.)edit/[id]/page.tsx
export default function EditModal(id){
...
const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof GuestSchema>) => {
    setError('')
    startTransition(() => {
      editGuest(values, id)
        .then((data) => {
          if (data?.error) {
            setError(data.error)
          }
          if (data?.success) {
            toast.success(data.success)
            router.back()
          }
        })
    })
  }
return {
...
<Button variant={'outline'} type='button' onClick={() => router.back()}>Close</Button>
<Button type='submit' disabled={isPending}>Submit</Button>
...
}


when running those onSubmit function and get response success, the URL changed to /admin/guestlist but the modal not dismissing.


but when i click the close button which have function ()=>router.back() the URL changed to /admin/guestlist and the modal can closed.

if you want to see the video, here i posted it on github disscussion
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50284#discussioncomment-8966036
i have already tried to use window.location.replace() and it works but  it will reset all the context and theres a blink 404 page for a sec then the modal closed
